# Iterate and assign value - Python - Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I´m a newbie in Python.

I´m trying to do something like this. Iterate an array, compare the value with a constant and assign values to another array.

[image: What I´m trying to do]

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Eduardo

Comment: Why is your code an image? Where did that come from?

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Eric, the image is from Smath. A software like Mathcad.

Comment: Divakar, the question is how can I iterate with index like in the image.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what's going on there for people not familiar with mathcad.

Comment: I don't know mathcad, so it's not clear to me, what you want to  do. Have a look at the python documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your comments. Sorry for the poor explanation. I'll try to explain myself better the next time.

Comment: In particular what is *f's* ? A derivative? A product? Or something else?

Comment: f´s is a new array that takes values from Ef o fy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question needs to be more specific BTW look how the element of a numpy `array` are accessed and modified:

```
>>> # generating a random numpy array
... np_array = numpy.random.randint(0,100,10)
>>> np_array
45: array([22, 71, 40, 83, 33, 52, 29, 31, 77, 87])
>>> # Replacing 26 with 30
... np_array[np_array == 26] = 30
>>> np_array
46: array([22, 71, 40, 83, 33, 52, 29, 31, 77, 87])
>>> # multiplying all the numbers less than 50 by 10
... np_array[np_array < 50] *= 10
>>> np_array
47: array([220,  71, 400,  83, 330,  52, 290, 310,  77,  87])
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: Thanks! I´ll try this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
a1 = numpy.array(range(10))
a2 = numpy.array(range(15,25))
print a2[a1==5]
print a2[a1 >= 8]
print a2[a1 < 5]
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks Joran, I´ll try this way.

Answer (score -1):

```
// A is the original list
// constant - f(y)

newList = list()
for i in A:
    if i < constant: newList.append(i)
    else: newList.append(constant)
```